# how to export bigquery to bigtable using airflow? schema issue

Tags: google-bigquery, dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable, airflow

I'm using Airflow to extract BigQuery rows to Google Cloud Storage in Avro format.

```
with models.DAG(
    "bigquery_to_bigtable",
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime.now(),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["test"],
) as dag:
    
    data_to_gcs = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id="data_to_gcs",
        project_id=project_id,
        location=location,
        configuration={
            "extract": {
                "destinationUri": gcs_uri, "destinationFormat": "AVRO",
                "sourceTable": {
                    "projectId": project_id, "datasetId": dataset_id, 
                    "tableId": table_id}}})

    gcs_to_bt = DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator(
        task_id="gcs_to_bt",
        template="gs://dataflow-templates/latest/GCS_Avro_to_Cloud_Bigtable",
        location=location,
        parameters={
            'bigtableProjectId': project_id,
            'bigtableInstanceId': bt_instance_id,
            'bigtableTableId': bt_table_id,
            'inputFilePattern': 'gs://export/test.avro-*'
        },
    )

data_to_gcs >> gcs_to_bt
```

the bigquery row contains

```
row_key      | 1_cnt | 2_cnt | 3_cnt
1#2021-08-03 |   1   |   2   |   2 
2#2021-08-02 |   5   |   1   |   5 
.
.
.
```

I'd like to use the `row_key` column for row key in bigtable and rest column for columns in specific column family like `my_cf` in bigtable.

However I got error messages while using dataflow to loads avro file to bigtable

```
"java.io.IOException: Failed to start reading from source: gs://export/test.avro-"
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found Root, expecting com.google.cloud.teleport.bigtable.BigtableRow, missing required field key
```

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#cloud-storage-avro-to-bigtable) I read is telling:

> The Bigtable table must exist and have the same column families as
> exported in the Avro files.

How Do I export BigQuery in Avro with same column families?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to transform AVRO to proper schema. [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#cloud-storage-avro-to-bigtable) mentioned by you also says:

> - Bigtable expects a specific schema from the input Avro files.

There is a [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/resources/schema/avro/bigtable.avsc) that is referring to special data schema, which has to be used.

If I understand correctly you are just importing data from table the result, although is AVRO schema, will not much the requirement schema, so you need to transform data to proper schema appropriate to your BigTable schema.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor I will give it a shot!

Comment: I'm sorry It was so late to choose your answer is correct. Now I can understand the schema for AVRO and can use it to import. Thanks!